# how to pass in array into udf spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a problem that 1) I don't really know how to call a registered UDF. I found some answer saying use callUDF so this is how I call the function in my code. 2) I don't really know how to pass in arrays as parameters.

Here is my code:

```
val df = Seq(("1","2","3","4","5","6")).toDF("A","B","C","D","E","F")
val newdf = Seq(("1","2","3","4","5","6")).toDF("A","B","C","D","E","F") 
val cols = df.columns


val temp = Array(df.select($"A"),df.select($"B"),df.select($"C"),df.select($"D"),df.select($"E"),df.select($"F"))
val temp2 = Array(newdf.select($"A"),newdf.select($"B"),newdf.select($"C"),newdf.select($"D"),newdf.select($"E"),newdf.select($"F"))


sparkSession.udf.register ( "myfunc" , ((A:Array[String],B:Array[String]) => {for(i <- 0 to 5)yield( if (A(i)==B(i)) "U" else "N")} ) )


val a = df.withColumn("A",callUDF("myfunc",(temp,temp2)))
```

Thanks in  advance!

Comment: can you explain what you are you trying to do?

Comment: @Shankar Koirala  trying to pass in temp and temp 1 to myfunc to compare the elements inside the two arrays

Comment: The arrays temp and temp1 contains dataframes is that what you want to compare ?

Comment: can you share the idea what you are trying to do

Comment: @Shankar Koirala  so basically it's like I need to compare anywhere from 6-12 cols in two different dataframe. So I am thinking put the columns I need to compare in arrays and pass them into a function then do a for loop to compare the columns inside the array

Comment: You can check out the below post on creating,registering and using udf in SparkSQL
    
     https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-window-functions-spark-harpreet-kaur

Comment: how many new columns do you want to add ?

Comment: @Shankar Koirala I don't want to add new columns, I need to compare them and return me a letter based on the comparison.

Comment: val a = df.withColumn("A",callUDF("myfunc",(temp,temp2))) this adds the new column named A

Comment: @Shankar Koirala yea that line was just to test if the function works...Now I can't even pass in the arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use columns from two different dataframes which is illegal in a UDF. Spark's UDF can only work on a per row basis. You can't combine rows from different dataframes. To do so you need to perform a join between the two.

In your case you have just one row but in a realistic case you would have multiple rows, you need to make sure you have some unique key to join by such as a unique id.

If you don't and both dataframes have the same number of rows and the same number of partitions you can easily create an id for both dataframes like this:

```
df.withColumn("id",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
```

You should probably also rename the columns to have different names.

Look at the different options for join (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) to see what best matches your need.

As for registering and calling a udf you can do:

```
def myFunc(s1: Seq[Int], s2: Seq[Int]) = {
  for(i <- 0 to 5) yield {
    if (s1(i)==s2(i)) "U" else "N"
  }
}
val u = udf(myFunc)
val a = df.withColumn("A", myFunc(temp,temp2))
```

note that temp and temp2 should each be a column representing an array **in the same dataframe**, i.e. you should define them after the join on the relevant columns.

Comment: hmm I do have a question, cuz somebody else passed in something like this udf(s.col1,s.col2,s.col3,t.col1.t.col2,t.col3), t and s are two different dataframes and this way the function can be called...?

Comment: is s and t belong to different dataframes then you can't call it on a UDF. what could happen is that s and t contained different columns from the same dataframe (i.e. they were not dataframes but instead some structure which was filled beforehand by relevant columns from the same dataframe).